# Create a shared folder on Amazon AWS Ubuntu Linux EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ubuntu-16.04, share

I have an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS server and would like to create a shared directory on this server that is accessible by a separate server running an RDS database. Both servers are in the same Virtual Private Cloud (VPC). The Ubuntu server will be a loader for the database. Read/Write access is required by the Loader to its shared directory and Read access is required by the Database Server. The Loader places files in this directory for bulk loading by the database server.

How do I create a shared folder in this context?
Am I to install samba or is there something simpler?

Comment: Which RDS DB engine are you using? Some of them can use S3 for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. RDS is a managed service that does not give you access to the underlying hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a directory for that.  I would do the following:

- Create a Security Group **loader-sec-group** for your Loader-EC2 instance.
- Create a Security Group **db-sec-group** that your DB instance will live in.
- Create a custom rule to allow connection from **loader-sec-group** to **db-sec-group**
- Feed the database directly from your Loader-EC2 with SQL

More informations: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html

Answer (score 0):

If are you intending to host your own DB on an EC2 Instance, you can have a shared folder between the two EC2 instances using EFS service (Elasting File System) Shared folders.

More about shared folders between EC2 using EFS
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-elastic-file-system-shared-file-storage-for-amazon-ec2/